# Exceedance in R

Tags: r

i have a time series of stock prices for example, and I would like to identify and highlight how many times a closing price is above a certain level for x consecutive days. 
I used the `RmarineHeatWaves::exceedance()` whish allows us to assign x and y vector in order to customize the data input. Buit there seem to be some restrictions/challenges. I get errors such as:

```
Error in exceedance(data = df.flags, x = Date, y = Price,  : 
  No temperatures over 130 degrees detected.
In addition: There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)
```

When the minimum and max values are:

```
> min(df.flags$Price, na.rm=T)
[1] 58.45261
> max(df.flags$Price, na.rm=T)
[1] 143.4189
```

I spent a day trying to understand their function and why in some case it would work and in some it would not. I think I should look for alternative.  Any suggestion please ?

```
df.flags
    doy       Date     Price
1     2 2019-01-02  58.76209
2     3 2019-01-03  58.45261
3     4 2019-01-04  59.65184
4     5 2019-01-05        NA
5     6 2019-01-06        NA
6     7 2019-01-07  60.30948
7     8 2019-01-08  59.11025
8     9 2019-01-09  59.34236
9    10 2019-01-10  58.91683
10   11 2019-01-11  59.11025
11   12 2019-01-12        NA
12   13 2019-01-13        NA
13   14 2019-01-14  59.03288
14   15 2019-01-15  60.69632
15   16 2019-01-16  60.34816
16   17 2019-01-17  62.05029
17   18 2019-01-18  63.59768
18   19 2019-01-19        NA
19   20 2019-01-20        NA
20   21 2019-01-21  68.85880
21   22 2019-01-22  68.51064
22   23 2019-01-23  70.32882
23   24 2019-01-24  69.63250
24   25 2019-01-25  71.37331
25   26 2019-01-26        NA
26   27 2019-01-27        NA
27   28 2019-01-28  72.30174
28   29 2019-01-29  72.41779
29   30 2019-01-30  72.34043
30   31 2019-01-31  70.98646
31   32 2019-02-01  71.56673
32   33 2019-02-02        NA
33   34 2019-02-03        NA
34   35 2019-02-04        NA
35   36 2019-02-05        NA
36   37 2019-02-06        NA
37   38 2019-02-07        NA
38   39 2019-02-08        NA
39   40 2019-02-09        NA
40   41 2019-02-10        NA
41   42 2019-02-11  74.66151
42   43 2019-02-12  73.96518
43   44 2019-02-13  73.96518
44   45 2019-02-14  73.15280
45   46 2019-02-15  71.64410
46   47 2019-02-16        NA
47   48 2019-02-17        NA
48   49 2019-02-18  73.81044
49   50 2019-02-19  73.15280
50   51 2019-02-20  72.49516
51   52 2019-02-21  72.18569
52   53 2019-02-22  70.79304
53   54 2019-02-23        NA
54   55 2019-02-24        NA
55   56 2019-02-25  73.96518
56   57 2019-02-26  71.64410
57   58 2019-02-27  72.80464
58   59 2019-02-28  72.92070
59   61 2019-03-01  77.75629
60   62 2019-03-02        NA
61   63 2019-03-03        NA
62   64 2019-03-04  77.13733
63   65 2019-03-05  77.29207
64   66 2019-03-06  76.90522
65   67 2019-03-07  76.55706
66   68 2019-03-08  71.91489
67   69 2019-03-09        NA
68   70 2019-03-10        NA
69   71 2019-03-11  74.08124
70   72 2019-03-12  74.35203
71   73 2019-03-13  76.71180
72   74 2019-03-14  77.56286
73   75 2019-03-15  82.51451
74   76 2019-03-16        NA
75   77 2019-03-17        NA
76   78 2019-03-18  85.57060
77   79 2019-03-19  86.46035
78   80 2019-03-20  85.02901
79   81 2019-03-21  85.91876
80   82 2019-03-22  86.26692
81   83 2019-03-23        NA
82   84 2019-03-24        NA
83   85 2019-03-25  86.53772
84   86 2019-03-26  86.26692
85   87 2019-03-27  92.76596
86   88 2019-03-28  90.63830
87   89 2019-03-29  93.50097
88   90 2019-03-30        NA
89   91 2019-03-31        NA
90   92 2019-04-01  94.81625
91   93 2019-04-02  93.26886
92   94 2019-04-03  91.72147
93   95 2019-04-04  91.76015
94   96 2019-04-05        NA
95   97 2019-04-06        NA
96   98 2019-04-07        NA
97   99 2019-04-08  89.09091
98  100 2019-04-09  90.48356
99  101 2019-04-10  91.25725
100 102 2019-04-11  86.69246
101 103 2019-04-12  87.46615
102 104 2019-04-13        NA
103 105 2019-04-14        NA
104 106 2019-04-15  85.33849
105 107 2019-04-16  87.00193
106 108 2019-04-17  85.72534
107 109 2019-04-18  86.11219
108 110 2019-04-19  87.46615
109 111 2019-04-20        NA
110 112 2019-04-21        NA
111 113 2019-04-22  91.29594
112 114 2019-04-23  93.65571
113 115 2019-04-24  94.42940
114 116 2019-04-25  85.02901
115 117 2019-04-26  84.33269
116 118 2019-04-27        NA
117 119 2019-04-28        NA
118 120 2019-04-29  89.90329
119 121 2019-04-30  89.63250
120 122 2019-05-01        NA
121 123 2019-05-02        NA
122 124 2019-05-03        NA
123 125 2019-05-04        NA
124 126 2019-05-05        NA
125 127 2019-05-06  87.11799
126 128 2019-05-07  89.59381
127 129 2019-05-08  90.48356
128 130 2019-05-09  85.68665
129 131 2019-05-10  88.89749
130 132 2019-05-11        NA
131 133 2019-05-12        NA
132 134 2019-05-13  92.45648
133 135 2019-05-14  93.19149
134 136 2019-05-15  95.55126
135 137 2019-05-16  97.33075
136 138 2019-05-17  96.94391
137 139 2019-05-18        NA
138 140 2019-05-19        NA
139 141 2019-05-20  95.04836
140 142 2019-05-21  94.62282
141 143 2019-05-22  96.55706
142 144 2019-05-23  95.41234
143 145 2019-05-24  92.19006
144 146 2019-05-25        NA
145 147 2019-05-26        NA
146 148 2019-05-27  92.13545
147 149 2019-05-28  93.28236
148 150 2019-05-29  92.40852
149 151 2019-05-30  94.04697
150 152 2019-05-31  96.55926
151 153 2019-06-01        NA
152 154 2019-06-02        NA
153 155 2019-06-03  98.63463
154 156 2019-06-04  95.35773
155 157 2019-06-05  96.77772
156 158 2019-06-06  97.43310
157 159 2019-06-07        NA
158 160 2019-06-08        NA
159 161 2019-06-09        NA
160 162 2019-06-10 100.38230
161 163 2019-06-11 104.09612
162 164 2019-06-12 103.76843
163 165 2019-06-13 110.54069
164 166 2019-06-14 112.50683
165 167 2019-06-15        NA
166 168 2019-06-16        NA
167 169 2019-06-17 110.43146
168 170 2019-06-18 110.32223
169 171 2019-06-19 109.66685
170 172 2019-06-20 114.41835
171 173 2019-06-21 112.61606
172 174 2019-06-22        NA
173 175 2019-06-23        NA
174 176 2019-06-24 113.16221
175 177 2019-06-25 118.13217
176 178 2019-06-26 122.22829
177 179 2019-06-27 123.42982
178 180 2019-06-28 130.36592
179 181 2019-06-29        NA
180 182 2019-06-30        NA
181 183 2019-07-01 143.41890
182 184 2019-07-02 138.99508
183 185 2019-07-03 134.40743
184 186 2019-07-04 127.14364
185 187 2019-07-05 128.23594
186 188 2019-07-06        NA
187 189 2019-07-07        NA
188 190 2019-07-08 123.42982
189 191 2019-07-09 123.42982
190 192 2019-07-10 119.87985
191 193 2019-07-11 120.15292
192 194 2019-07-12 121.19061
193 195 2019-07-13        NA
194 196 2019-07-14        NA
195 197 2019-07-15 121.62753
196 198 2019-07-16 117.85909
197 199 2019-07-17 116.00218
198 200 2019-07-18 113.10759
199 201 2019-07-19 113.05298
200 202 2019-07-20        NA
201 203 2019-07-21        NA
202 204 2019-07-22 111.74222
203 205 2019-07-23 113.05298
204 206 2019-07-24 111.85145
205 207 2019-07-25 115.78372
206 208 2019-07-26 117.09448
207 209 2019-07-27        NA
208 210 2019-07-28        NA
209 211 2019-07-29 116.22064
210 212 2019-07-30 113.87220
211 213 2019-07-31 109.22993
212 214 2019-08-01 107.59148
213 215 2019-08-02 109.12070
214 216 2019-08-03        NA
215 217 2019-08-04        NA
216 218 2019-08-05 105.35227
217 219 2019-08-06 106.77226
218 220 2019-08-07 104.15074
219 221 2019-08-08 104.36920
220 222 2019-08-09 103.00382
221 223 2019-08-10        NA
222 224 2019-08-11        NA
223 225 2019-08-12 104.31458
224 226 2019-08-13 104.09612
225 227 2019-08-14 108.13763
226 228 2019-08-15 115.40142
227 229 2019-08-16 115.94757
228 230 2019-08-17        NA
229 231 2019-08-18        NA
230 232 2019-08-19 117.20371
231 233 2019-08-20 115.29219
232 234 2019-08-21 113.59913
233 235 2019-08-22 113.21682
234 236 2019-08-23 117.09448
235 237 2019-08-24        NA
236 238 2019-08-25        NA
237 239 2019-08-26 112.67067
238 240 2019-08-27 121.57291
239 241 2019-08-28 121.24522
240 242 2019-08-29 121.79137
241 243 2019-08-30 124.79519
242 244 2019-08-31        NA
243 245 2019-09-01        NA
244 246 2019-09-02 123.86674
245 247 2019-09-03 121.08138
246 248 2019-09-04 120.64446
247 249 2019-09-05 120.26215
248 250 2019-09-06 119.22447
249 251 2019-09-07        NA
250 252 2019-09-08        NA
251 253 2019-09-09 120.15292
252 254 2019-09-10 125.83288
253 255 2019-09-11 122.39214
254 256 2019-09-12 122.33752
255 257 2019-09-13        NA
256 258 2019-09-14        NA
257 259 2019-09-15        NA
258 260 2019-09-16 119.87985
259 261 2019-09-17 116.65756
260 262 2019-09-18 118.84216
261 263 2019-09-19 119.16985
262 264 2019-09-20 122.06445
263 265 2019-09-21        NA
264 266 2019-09-22        NA
265 267 2019-09-23 119.06062
266 268 2019-09-24 119.16985
267 269 2019-09-25 120.80830
268 270 2019-09-26 120.09831


exc_25 <- exceedance(data = df.flags, x = Date , y = Price, threshold = 130, min_duration = 20, below = FALSE, max_gap = 0)


Error in exceedance(data = df.flags, x = Date, y = Price, threshold = 130,  : 
  No temperatures over 130 degrees detected.
In addition: There were 28 warnings (use warnings() to see them)
```

when it works, the result should look like this (Example on another stock where it works fine):

```
$threshold
# A tibble: 268 x 7
   Date       Price thresh thresh_criterion duration_criterion exceedance exceedance_no
   <date>      <dbl>  <dbl> <lgl>            <lgl>              <lgl>              <int>
 1 2019-01-02   86.3    130 FALSE            FALSE              FALSE                 NA
 2 2019-01-03   83.3    130 FALSE            FALSE              FALSE                 NA
 3 2019-01-04   87.4    130 FALSE            FALSE              FALSE                 NA
 4 2019-01-05   88.1    130 FALSE            FALSE              FALSE                 NA
 5 2019-01-06   88.8    130 FALSE            FALSE              FALSE                 NA
 6 2019-01-07   89.6    130 FALSE            FALSE              FALSE                 NA
 7 2019-01-08   89.2    130 FALSE            FALSE              FALSE                 NA
 8 2019-01-09   89.4    130 FALSE            FALSE              FALSE                 NA
 9 2019-01-10   88.3    130 FALSE            FALSE              FALSE                 NA
10 2019-01-11   89.3    130 FALSE            FALSE              FALSE                 NA
# ... with 258 more rows

$exceedance
  index_start index_stop exceedance_no duration date_start  date_stop  date_peak int_mean  int_max
1          60        116             1       57 2019-03-02 2019-04-27 2019-03-22 17.74578 41.44654
   int_var  int_cum int_mean_abs int_max_abs int_var_abs int_cum_abs rate_onset rate_decline
1 9.018233 1011.509     147.7458    171.4465    9.018233    8421.509   1.954287     1.182045
```

The dataset for the one that is working is :

```
  Date        Price
1   2019-01-02  102.17077
2   2019-01-03  96.67149
3   2019-01-04  100.14472
4   2019-01-07  110.13025
5   2019-01-08  108.53835
6   2019-01-09  119.39219
7   2019-01-10  115.62952
8   2019-01-11  116.06368
9   2019-01-14  118.23444
10  2019-01-15  115.62952
11  2019-01-16  113.31404
12  2019-01-17  113.16932
13  2019-01-18  109.55137
14  2019-01-21  111.43271
15  2019-01-22  109.40666
16  2019-01-23  110.56440
17  2019-01-24  111.43271
18  2019-01-25  106.65702
19  2019-01-28  103.76266
20  2019-01-29  103.03907
21  2019-01-30  100.00000
22  2019-01-31  99.13169
23  2019-02-01  101.01302
24  2019-02-11  104.92041
25  2019-02-12  105.78871
26  2019-02-13  109.84081
27  2019-02-14  110.99855
28  2019-02-15  109.40666
29  2019-02-18  113.31404
30  2019-02-19  111.28799
31  2019-02-20  122.43126
32  2019-02-21  124.31259
33  2019-02-22  126.04920
34  2019-02-25  131.98263
35  2019-02-26  125.90449
36  2019-02-27  129.23300
37  2019-02-28  123.29957
38  2019-03-01  125.18090
39  2019-03-04  128.79884
40  2019-03-05  134.00868
41  2019-03-06  131.54848
42  2019-03-07  134.58755
43  2019-03-08  121.27352
44  2019-03-11  128.79884
45  2019-03-12  141.67873
46  2019-03-13  131.83792
47  2019-03-14  125.18090
48  2019-03-15  126.19392
49  2019-03-18  133.42981
50  2019-03-19  146.74385
51  2019-03-20  161.36035
52  2019-03-21  177.56874
53  2019-03-22  195.36903
54  2019-03-25  177.71346
55  2019-03-26  159.91317
56  2019-03-27  165.99132
57  2019-03-28  156.29522
58  2019-03-29  161.07091
59  2019-04-01  177.13459
60  2019-04-02  173.37192
61  2019-04-03  169.03039
62  2019-04-04  170.76700
63  2019-04-08  167.00434
64  2019-04-09  174.67438
65  2019-04-10  169.03039
66  2019-04-11  158.90014
67  2019-04-12  159.04486
68  2019-04-15  157.01881
69  2019-04-16  167.72793
70  2019-04-17  164.39942
71  2019-04-18  159.62373
72  2019-04-19  160.63676
73  2019-04-22  163.53111
74  2019-04-23  179.88423
75  2019-04-24  170.47757
76  2019-04-25  187.55427
77  2019-04-26  186.68596
78  2019-04-29  168.01737
79  2019-04-30  151.23010
80  2019-05-06  136.17945
81  2019-05-07  137.04776
82  2019-05-08  135.89001
83  2019-05-09  138.92909
84  2019-05-10  146.88857
85  2019-05-13  150.21708
86  2019-05-14  159.62373
87  2019-05-15  162.37337
88  2019-05-16  157.45297
89  2019-05-17  147.61216
90  2019-05-20  154.55861
91  2019-05-21  153.40087
92  2019-05-22  154.84805
93  2019-05-23  144.13893
94  2019-05-24  141.82344
95  2019-05-27  147.90159
96  2019-05-28  150.65123
97  2019-05-29  148.48046
98  2019-05-30  144.86252
99  2019-05-31  149.34877
100 2019-06-03  164.25470
101 2019-06-04  169.03039
102 2019-06-05  185.96237
103 2019-06-06  167.43849
104 2019-06-10  161.93922
105 2019-06-11  165.99132
106 2019-06-12  170.91172
107 2019-06-13  165.94203
108 2019-06-14  154.49275
109 2019-06-17  159.42029
110 2019-06-18  156.37681
111 2019-06-19  159.13043
112 2019-06-20  163.04348
113 2019-06-21  163.47826
114 2019-06-24  164.49275
115 2019-06-25  159.42029
116 2019-06-26  160.86957
117 2019-06-27  163.47826
118 2019-06-28  156.52174
119 2019-07-01  160.86957
120 2019-07-02  157.97101
121 2019-07-03  151.73913
122 2019-07-04  148.84058
123 2019-07-05  149.56522
124 2019-07-08  141.30435
125 2019-07-09  142.02899
126 2019-07-10  141.73913
127 2019-07-11  140.43478
128 2019-07-12  142.02899
129 2019-07-15  151.01449
130 2019-07-16  150.14493
131 2019-07-17  148.26087
132 2019-07-18  143.62319
133 2019-07-19  142.60870
134 2019-07-22  135.65217
135 2019-07-23  136.95652
136 2019-07-24  138.84058
137 2019-07-25  141.15942
138 2019-07-26  141.15942
139 2019-07-29  142.02899
140 2019-07-30  141.30435
141 2019-07-31  138.26087
142 2019-08-01  136.08696
143 2019-08-02  132.02899
144 2019-08-05  128.11594
145 2019-08-06  120.43478
146 2019-08-07  120.14493
147 2019-08-08  121.88406
148 2019-08-09  120.28986
149 2019-08-12  121.88406
150 2019-08-13  120.43478
151 2019-08-14  120.43478
152 2019-08-15  121.73913
153 2019-08-16  121.59420
154 2019-08-19  126.08696
155 2019-08-20  130.14493
156 2019-08-21  127.68116
157 2019-08-22  130.57971
158 2019-08-23  127.53623
159 2019-08-26  123.33333
160 2019-08-27  124.63768
161 2019-08-28  126.95652
162 2019-08-29  130.57971
163 2019-08-30  125.79710
164 2019-09-02  130.28986
165 2019-09-03  135.21739
166 2019-09-04  133.76812
167 2019-09-05  138.84058
168 2019-09-06  143.76812
169 2019-09-09  155.79710
170 2019-09-10  150.72464
171 2019-09-11  147.53623
172 2019-09-12  149.85507
173 2019-09-16  147.53623
174 2019-09-17  140.14493
175 2019-09-18  139.42029
176 2019-09-19  143.47826
177 2019-09-20  144.20290
178 2019-09-23  142.89855
179 2019-09-24  143.33333
180 2019-09-25  143.47826
```

Comment: Can you create a small mock dataset and show expected output based on that ?

Comment: Hey Ronak, I just added.

Comment: Can you share the example (data) for which the function works ?

Comment: Hey, can do in about 1hr brb

Comment: Hey Ronak, Apologies for the delay. I just added the dataset that is working. 181 entries. Just with the eyes, i am not sure if we can tell what is not working.

Comment: Ok, i will work later on this, for now I do not launch the exceedance function unless there are x amount of observation above the threhshold accross the dataframe.

Comment: What I have found it is based on `min_duration` value `exceedance` divides the data into groups and each group value should have a value above `threshold`. When your `min_duration = 20` there is no value in 1st group which is above `threshold` i.e 130 hence you get the error. Try running `exceedance(df.flags, x = Date, y = Price, threshold = 60, min_duration = 20, below = FALSE, max_gap = 0)` and `exceedance(df.flags, x = Date, y = Price, threshold = 60, min_duration = 10, below = FALSE, max_gap = 0)` you get output of 2 and 3 rows respectively and they run with some warnings but without error